# "Definitely how many" Usage

Tags: meaning

One of the question given in the text book starts with 'Definitely how many students are there?'

Does this mean "the exact number of students" or 'The minimum number of students'?

May be a silly question, but I am confused, probably because I am thinking in own native language

Comment: What textbook is this? It seems a very odd question. I don't know what it's supposed to mean.

Comment: This use of definitely is very strange and I do not think you should try to use it in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say, since you have an erroneous use of "definitely," a verb modifier that means clearly, certainly, or surely.  We can infer (i.e., guess) that it's an attempt to give an example of the opposite of this question:

> **Approximately** how many students are there?

That opposite-sense would be phrased

> **Exactly** how many student are there?

Each of the bold adverbs modifies "many," a task that "definitely" isn't up to.

Comment: Not entirely sure about the argument, thougfh your conclusion is clearly right. *How many students are definitely there?*  would be acceptable, though it might be a different sense of 'there'.

Comment: @TimLymington My argument is that "definitely" can't modify "many," the way "approximately" and "exactly" can, which leaves "definitely" to modify the verb (or the whole clause), which is a little odd.  When you ask how many students are definitely there, does that mean we're to omit the ones who are daydreaming or just the revenants?  It's fine to say "Can you state definitely how many students are there?" but then it's about the counter, not the counted.

Comment: A maths problem about overlapping percentages could certainly ask *How many students are definitely there?*  meaning 'at a minimum'. OPs sentence could mean that, though I agree it would not be ideal phrasing.

Comment: I think "definitely" sounds weird because it seems to imply there could be some uncertainty as to the actual location of the students.